# How to use alias in @Formula

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So today I just run into a problem where @Formula is not working as I expected. Let say:

**Database**

```
year |  X  |  Y 
-----+-----+-----
2010 |  A  |  10
2011 |  A  |  20
2011 |  B  |  99
2009 |  C  |  30
2010 |  C  |  40
```

I want to get the year with the highest 'Y' and group by 'X', so I write a query like this

```
SELECT year
FROM (SELECT
        year,
        MAX(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ) max_y
      FROM TableB) q
WHERE year = '2011' and x = 'A';
```

**So the result is**

```
year |
-----+
2011 |
```

Then I want to use it in entity so I create entity with @Formula

```
@Formula("(SELECT year FROM (SELECT b.year, MAX(b.y) OVER(PARTITION BY b.x) max_y FROM TableB b) q WHERE year = '2011' AND x = 'A')")
private String yearWithHighestScore;
```

But Hibernate processes into:

```
(select entity0_.year as year1_8_ 
from (select b.year as name, max(b.y) over(partition by b.year) entity0_.max_y from TableB b) entity0_.q 
where entity0_.year=? and entity0_.x=?) as formula0_1_
```

You see Hibernate convert it into "entity0_.max_y" which is not correct because max_y is not a column of table TableB; it just an alias of calculated column

**My question:** Can we have any way to tell Hibernate it is alias of the column, it's not a column name itself ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to  use alias for sub-query: `SELECT q.name FROM (SELECT b.fullName name, b.email FROM TableB b) AS q`

Comment: Why would you want to select three columns in the subquery and then only use one? I fail to see why the query nesting is even needed in your scenario

Comment: Max FarsiKov even q will be translated to entity0_.q

Comment: crizzis I've edited so we have the clear scenario now.

Comment: @ToanDao if you have a solution pls give your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Prefix alias name with '_':

```
@Formula("(SELECT year FROM (SELECT b.year, MAX(b.y) OVER(PARTITION BY b.x) _max_y FROM TableB b) _q WHERE year = '2011' AND x = 'A')")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Oracle databases. Aliases cannot start with _ unless they are wrapped in double-quotes. Unfortunately, having the double quotes results in the entity prefix again.

Comment: worked for me for both mysql and h2. Thank you!

Comment: This one not worked for Oracle database. If you have a solution for Oracle database, it will helpful for us!

Comment: worked for me on sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a oracle view like the below which converts the alias into a column

```
 create or replace view TABLE_V as 
 SELECT
    year,
    MAX(y) OVER (PARTITION BY x ) max_y,
    x
  FROM TableB ;
```

and then use

```
SELECT year from TABLE_V where year='2011' and x='A';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hibernate bug and it is been raised on their bug reports.

you can follow up with this bug on the link
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15405